# Which one is more efficient?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a Python program for deleting duplicates from a list of names.

But I'm in a dilemma and searching out for a most efficient way out of both means.

I have uploaded a list of names to a SQLite DB, into a column in a table.

Whether comparing the names and deleting the duplicates out of them in a DB is good or loading them to Python means getting them into Python and deleting the duplicates and pushing them back to the DB is good?

I'm confused and here is a piece of code to do it on SQLite:

```
dup_killer (member_id, date) SELECT * FROM talks GROUP BY member_id,
```

Comment: If you are pushing them back to DB, why don't you store them in the deduped way in DB in the first place?

Comment: yes @spicavigo , But is that code correct ! or can u please let me know the specific code ?

Comment: Your sample piece of code does not look complete to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the names as a key in the database, the database will make sure they are not duplicated.  So there would be no reason to ship the list to Python and de-dup there.

If you haven't inserted the names into the database yet, you might as well de-dup them in Python first.  It is probably faster to do it in Python using the built-in features than to incur the overhead of repeated attempts to insert to the database.

(By the way: you can really speed up the insertion of many names if you wrap all the inserts in a single transaction.  Start a transaction, insert all the names, and finish the transaction.  The database does some work to make sure that the database is consistent, and it's *much* more efficient to do that work once for a whole list of names, rather than doing it once per name.)

If you have the list in Python, you can de-dup it very quickly using built-in features.  The two common features that are useful for de-duping are the `set` and the `dict`.

I have given you three examples.  The simplest case is where you have a list that just contains names, and you want to get a list with just unique names; you can just put the list into a `set`.  The second case is that your list contains records and you need to extract the name part to build the set.  The third case shows how to build a `dict` that maps a name onto a record, then inserts the record into a database; like a `set`, a `dict` will only allow unique values to be used as keys.  When the `dict` is built, it will keep the *last* value from the list with the same name.

```
# list already contains names
unique_names = set(list_of_all_names)
unique_list = list(unique_names) # lst now contains only unique names

# extract record field from each record and make set
unique_names = set(x.name for x in list_of_all_records)
unique_list = list(unique_names) # lst now contains only unique names

# make dict mapping name to a complete record
d = dict((x.name, x) for x in list_of_records)
# insert complete record into database using name as key
for name in d:
    insert_into_database(d[name])
```

Comment: None of your methods preserve the original order of the list. That may not matter, but if it does `unique_names = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(list_of_all_names))` will preserve the first occurrence of each name.

Comment: @Duncan, I would be very surprised indeed if it was important to preserve the order of names inserted into a database table.  But I like that trick and I'll remember it.  Thanks for sharing it.